# Atualizar uma linha do CSV sem ter que percorrer ele todo c#

Tags: c#, arquivo, csv

Teria como eu atualizar uma linha especifica  do arquivo CSV? eu tenho a informação de qual linha eu quero acrescentar informação, atualmente tenho o código que percorre o arquivo e quando chega na linha que eu quero ele atualiza a linha e continua escrevendo o resto das linhas, porem isso esta me causando uma perca de performasse, pois meu arquivo é muito grande, se alguém souber como editar usando algum parâmetro para ir direto na linha como se fosse um array?

```
   public  string EscreveCSV(string caminho, int linha, string mensagem)
    {
        //Só continua se o arquivo informado existir
        if (File.Exists(caminho))
        {
            //lista que irá armazenar cada linha do arquivo
            List<string> linhas = new List<string>();


            using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(caminho, Encoding.Default))
            {
                string sLinha = null;
                while ((sLinha = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    linhas.Add(sLinha); //adiciona cada linha do arquivo à lista
                }

                tr.Close();
                tr.Dispose();

            }

            //Só continua se o arquivo ter um número maior de linhas informadas
            if (linhas.Count > linha)
            {
                linhas[linha] += ";" + mensagem; //adiciona a mensagem informada ao final da linha

                using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(caminho, false, Encoding.Default))
                {
                    foreach (string l in linhas)
                    {
                        tw.WriteLine(l); //escreve no arquivo novamente
                    }

                    tw.Close();
                }

                return "Arquivo Escrito com sucesso"; //mensagem de retorno
            }
            else
            {
                return "Arquivo Não possui a linha informada";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "Arquivo não existe";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Poste o código atual

Comment: Pronto @VirgilioNovic

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui https://superuser.com/questions/7169/querying-a-csv-file

Comment: @Denis, olhei porem nao encontrei como isso poderia me ajudar e acredito que ele nao esteja usando o C#

Comment: Tem uma maneira de pegar todas as linhas, ai faz a verificação depois gravar de novo, talvez  (sem teste não tem como afirmar se é mais performático) porque, se faz o processo manual é deve ser bem demorado mesmo

Comment: CSV é um arquivo de texto, a menos que a nova linha tenha exatamente o mesmo número de caracteres da que está sendo substituída não tem como alterar sem recriar o arquivo todo

Comment: @VirgilioNovic  vou ver se consigo fazer algo seguindo essa linha de raciocínio

Comment: @LeandroGodoyRosa nao seria substituir e sim acrescentar uma informação no final da linha

Comment: @JhonatasSilva vou propor um esboço teste e me fala o que deu se foi mais performático.

Comment: @JhonatasSilva quantas linhas tem o seu arquivo?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic estou tentando com um aquivo que tem 206 colunas e 300 linhas porem faço validação em todas as os campos/linha, ai quando encontro um erro essa validação chamo o método que escreve esse erro no CSV

Comment: @JhonatasSilva não é melhor abrir o arquivo em memória, verifica o erro, altera, e ai até acabar e grava tudo!?

Comment: Manipular em memória é sempre melhor, a menos que seja para fazer uma alteração solta e fechar logo a seguir

Comment: Pessoal agradeço o comentário de todos, foi muito valido, consegui resolver o problema, ao invés de ficar lendo e gravando na planilha (CSV) a todo momento e joguei as informações em uma lista, faço toda a manipulação dos dados que preciso e só no final escrevo no CSV, aumento  muito a performasse, vou colocar compartilhar aqui o código que lista  a planilha inicialmente, e o que faz atualização nas linhas que preciso.

Comment: So tentar deletar, adicionar, modificar, buscar etc... e depois de um tempo vc vai perceber porque foi criado SQL...

Answer (score -1):

Código usando para passar o conteúdo do CSV para uma Lista de string:

```
 public List<string> PlanilhaCSV(string caminho)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        List<string> lista = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(caminho))
            {

                string linha = null;


                while ((linha = rd.ReadLine()) != null)
                {

                    lista.Add(linha.ToString());

                }

                rd.Close();
                rd.Dispose();

                    return lista;


            }
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Não foi possivel localizar o arquivo " + caminho);

        }
        return lista;
    }
```

//Codigo usado para adicionar um log de erro em uma linha especifica

```
     public List<string> AdionaLog(List<string> lista, int linha, string mensagem)
    {
        List<string> linhas = new List<string>();
        int contador = 1;
        foreach (var x in lista)
        {


            if (contador == linha)
                linhas.Add(x + ";" + mensagem);

            else
                linhas.Add(x.ToString());

            contador++;
        }



        return linhas;


    }
```

// Escrevendo por fim na planilha o conteúdo da Lista

```
   public void PlanilhaSaida(List<string> lista, string caminho)
    {


        using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(caminho, false, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            foreach (string l in lista)
            {
                tw.WriteLine(l);
            }

            tw.Close();
        }




    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Acho que isso deve resolver seu problema de performance.

```
 public string UpdateLine(string pathCSV, int line, string message)
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(pathCSV))
        {
            var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(pathCSV, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

            if(lines.Count() >= line)
            {
                lines[line -1] += ";" + message; //adiciona a mensagem informada ao final da linha
                System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(pathCSV, lines, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

                return "Arquivo Escrito com sucesso";
            }
            return "Arquivo Não possui a linha informada";
        }
        return "Arquivo não existe";
    }
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).